# Why is bash stopping processing the script

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm generating a script like this

```
(echo "ssh hans@mymachine.com echo hello" ; echo 'echo Done')
```

which produces

```
ssh hans@mymachine.com echo hello
echo Done
```

If I store the generated script in a file

```
(echo "ssh hans@mymachine.com echo hello" ; echo 'echo Done') > a.sh
```

and execute it

```
. ./a.sh
```

then it works oke and produces

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
hello
Done
```

If I'm executing the script by piping these commands to bash

```
(echo "ssh hans@mymachine.com echo hello" ; echo 'echo Done') | bash
```

The result is

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
hello
```

As you can see bash did not execute the 'echo Done' command.

My first thought was that ssh probably produces a non zero return value probaby caused by this xauth warning. So I did this

```
ssh hans@mymachine.com echo hello
echo $?
```

which produced

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
hello
0
```

So return value is oke. Now I tried using a trap

```
trap "" ERR
```

but this also didn't help. Pretty logical as the return value was zero anyway.

So I'm lost. Why is the 'echo Done' command not being executed?

UPDATE:

I noticed that when I wrap the script with brackets it works. So

```
( echo "(" ; echo "ssh hans@mymachine.com echo hello" ; echo 'echo Done'; echo ")" ) | bash
```

produces

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
hello
Done
```

Comment: Does ssh authentication work if executed directly?

Comment: The hello command is executed (see response) so yes, authentication works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh` is consuming stdin, which in this case is the `echo`. Add `-n`.

Comment: this doesn't sound logical as the ssh command has finished when the 'echo Done' is executed. If its finished it cannot consume anything.

Comment: *Before* ssh has finished executing, it consumes stdin. *Including* the incoming "echo 'echo Done'".

Comment: The 'echo Done' command is executed after the ssh command. It cannot consume output from a command that is executed after it. If I replace the 'echo Done' with 'echo Done >file.txt' the file is not created so the command is not executed at all.

Comment: Correct. `bash` and `ssh` share the same stdin, therefore `ssh` consumes the external `echo` before it has a chance to send to `bash`.

Comment: No, not correct. Please read my last comment. The 'echo Done' command is not executed at all so its NOT a matter of consuming stdin.

Comment: That command is being *input* via stdin. Of *course* it's being consumed.

Comment: oke I get it now (finally). Ssh is using the same stdin as the bash process which is executing the ssh command which is passed through the pipe. So it is reading the 'echo Done' command. The parameter -n prevents ssh to read from stdin such the 'echo Done' command will be processed by bash. Thanks